# mounting an old raid external hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, raid

New to the group. I have an old MyBook external, networked hard drive that windows could not connect to. I removed the hard drive and threw everything else away (should not have done) thinking I would just connect it as an external hard drive. I then figured out that is was a raid drive with a linux file system and it would not boot to the windows machine. I have a an Ubuntu machine that will not auto detect the drive. I can see it using the gnome drive tool or through the terminal. All of our digital pictures are on this drive so I do want to lose it.

Can this be mounted manually without damaging the drive?

```
Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         64320    3984191    3919872   1.9G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       3984192    4498175     513984   251M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       4498176    6474175    1976000 964.9M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4       6474176 1953520064 1947045889 928.4G fd Linux raid autodetect
```

Thanks for the help

Jeff Thomass

Comment: yes you will be able to mount the drive here is Ubuntu's help page on mounting new drives https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive as to weather there is usable data on the drive depends on what raid level the drive was setup with here is the wiki on raid levels https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels